# Customize Cloudflare Stream Player by remove the gear icon

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflarestream

I’m trying to remove just **setting the gear icon** but If I set false for controls it’s going out all other like Play/Pause.

If I’m using my own player it’s ok BUT I want to use Cloudflare Player, not my custom player. Because in Cloudflare player there have **1x auto** and other options which are not in my player. (**[Using the player API](https://developers.cloudflare.com/stream/viewing-videos/using-the-player-api)**)

Can **anyone help me** by giving a code example ?

```
<iframe
  src="https://iframe.videodelivery.net/$5d5bc37ffcf54c9b82e996823bffbb81"
  style="border: none;"
  height="555"
  width="666"
  allow="accelerometer; gyroscope; autoplay; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture;"
  allowfullscreen="true"
  id="stream-player"
></iframe>

<script src="https://embed.videodelivery.net/embed/sdk.latest.js"></script>

<!-- Your JavaScript code below-->
<script>
  const player = Stream(document.getElementById('stream-player'))
  player.addEventListener('play', () => {
    console.log('playing!')
  })
  player.play().catch(() => {
    console.log('playback failed, muting to try again')
    player.muted = true
    player.play()
  })
</script>
```